# Find the matrices A_1, A_2, A_3 in M2x2 that span the Kernel of T.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The problem says:

Let M$_{2x2}$ be the vector space of 2x2 matrices and let T: M$_{2x2}$ -> M$_{2x2}$ be the linear transformation defined by T(A) = A - A$^T$ for all A in M$_{2x2}$. Find the matrices A$_1$, A$_2$, A$_3$ in M$_{2x2}$ which span the Kernel of T.

I am lost because I don't know what a Kernel is. Could some body please explain how to do this problem?

Comment: $T^T$?  you mean perhaps $A^T$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U$ and $V$ be vector spaces and let $0\in V$ be the identity element of $V$.  Let $T$ be a linear transformation from $U$ to $V$.

> The **Kernel** of $T$ (*also called the Nullspace of T*) is defined to be:
>
> $$\ker(T):=\{u\in V~:~T(u)=0\in V\}$$
>
> In other words, it is the set of all inputs which get mapped to "zero."

Assuming a typo in the above, and your transformation is meant to be defined as $T(A)=A-A^{\top}$ (*where $A^{\top}$ denotes the transpose of $A$*), we are tasked with finding how we can describe the set of matrices $A$ such that $T(A)=0$.

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2\\a_3&a_4\end{bmatrix}$

Then $T(A)=A-A^{\top} = \begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2\\a_3&a_4\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_3\\a_2&a_4\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0&a_2-a_3\\a_3-a_2&0\end{bmatrix}$

When is that equal to the zero matrix?

Do any of the values $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ depend on one another to make the above the zero matrix?  Are there any values which don't affect whether or not it becomes the zero matrix?

Comment: Wow it makes so much sense now... Thank you so much!